# JobScheduler in periodic time not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jobscheduler

JobSchedule is not working periodically. Here is the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".receiver.BootCompletedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".JobScheduleService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
            android:exported="true"/>
    </application>
```

Then in MainActivity.kt, I have initialized and scheduled the job

```
val jobScheduler = applicationContext
                .getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
        val componentName = ComponentName(this,
                JobScheduleService::class.java!!)
        val jobInfoObj = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) Builder(777, componentName)
                // create a job that stays as scheduled even after device reboots,
                // you need call setPersisted() method by passing true as value to it
                .setPersisted(true)
                // create a job that needs to be rerun if it fails,
                // you need to use setBackOffCriteria() method passing time interval
                // for the first time retry and retry policy which is used to calculate
                // time interval for retries after first retry.
                .setBackoffCriteria(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(2000), BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR)
                .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(2000), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(3000))
                .build() else {
            TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < N")
        }

        jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfoObj);
```

And here is the JobService class:

```
class JobScheduleService:JobService(){

    override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        Log.d("1", "onStartJob")
        sendMessage(1, params = params)
        return true
    }

    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        Log.d("1", "onStopJob")
        sendMessage(2, params = params)
        return true
    }

    private fun sendMessage(messageID: Int, params: JobParameters?) {
        // If this service is launched by the JobScheduler, there's no callback Messenger. It
        // only exists when the MainActivity calls startService() with the callback in the Intent.
        try {
            Timer().schedule(timerTask {
                Log.e(messageID.toString(), "job finished")
                jobFinished(params, true)
            }, 2000)
            Log.i(messageID.toString(), "sending message on schedule")

        } catch (e: RemoteException) {
            Log.e(messageID.toString(), "Error passing service object back to activity.")
        }
        finally {


        }

    }
}
```

When I am running the build, it is logging below message, and then never the onStart/onStop methods get invoked.

```
09-20 14:02:48.330 9417-9417/com.thakur.android.jobscheduler W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
09-20 14:02:48.438 9417-9417/com.thakur.android.jobscheduler D/1: onStartJob
09-20 14:02:48.439 9417-9417/com.thakur.android.jobscheduler I/1: sending message on schedule
09-20 14:02:50.440 9417-9568/com.thakur.android.jobscheduler E/1: job finished
09-20 14:02:53.201 9417-9500/com.thakur.android.jobscheduler I/pending: 1
09-20 14:02:58.202 9417-9500/com.thakur.android.jobscheduler I/pending: 1
09-20 14:03:03.204 9417-9500/com.thakur.android.jobscheduler I/pending: 1
...
09-20 14:16:53.269 9417-9500/com.thakur.android.jobscheduler I/pending: 1
09-20 14:16:58.270 9417-9500/com.thakur.android.jobscheduler I/pending: 1
09-20 14:17:03.270 9417-9500/com.thakur.android.jobscheduler I/pending: 1
```

Comment: Here is the complete sample code for it. https://github.com/ankitthakur/JobScheduler